# LMS (Lambda-Mu-Sigma) method in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, percentile

I want to create percentile curves for my data using LMS (Lambda-Mu-Sigma) method. I have following example data. How can 10th, 50th and 90th percentile curves of yvar (on y-axis) vs age (on x-axis) be drawn using LMS?

```
age = sample(5:75, 500, replace=T) 
yvar = rnorm(500, age, 20)
mydata = data.frame(age, yvar)
head(mydata)
  age     yvar
1  61 87.16011
2  58 49.73289
3  65 15.60212
4  71 83.32699
5  33 40.89592
6  18 25.04376

plot(age, yvar)
```

[image]

I came across VGAM package http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/VGAM/docs/lms.bcn . Is that the best method to do it? I could not really understand its example code to create simple percentile curve from above data. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are basically asking for a mini-tutorial. That's bit more along the lines of what CrossValidated.com supports. Questions on SO are supposed to be requests for implementation of a definite strategy. That said I've only previously seen the LMS implemented in the gamlss::lms function, so would not be very much help coding with a VGAM approach. (It doesn't look like a transformation to normaility is needed.) If you get to the point of actually knowing what you are doing, then edit this question to have code and examples ... perhaps using data from one of the help pages.

Comment: the other issue here is that anything LMS/Box-Cox based is going to require non-negative response variables.

Comment: @BondedDust : I tried CrossValidated.com but they said it is an R question.

Comment: @BenBolker : How can we use it for non-negative response variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simulate data (reproducibly):

```
set.seed(1001)
mydata <- data.frame(
   age = sample(5:75, 500, replace=TRUE))
mydata <- transform(mydata,
   yvar = rnorm(500, age, 20))
```

Since the [LMS](http://www.indianpediatrics.net/jan2014/jan-37-43.htm) method typically appears to be based on variants of the [Box-Cox transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform), which requires positive values, a simpler way to do this would be to use [quantile regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression).

```
library("quantreg")
library("ggplot2"); theme_set(theme_bw())
g0 <- ggplot(mydata,aes(x=age,y=yvar))+geom_point()
g0 + geom_smooth(method="rq",tau=c(0.1),se=FALSE,lty=2)+
      geom_smooth(method="rq",tau=c(0.5),se=FALSE)+
      geom_smooth(method="rq",tau=c(0.9),se=FALSE,lty=2)
```

`rq()` by itself has the capability to fit all three percentiles at the same time, but you need to use the strategy suggested in [this blog post](http://martinsbioblogg.wordpress.com/2013/06/02/using-r-drawing-several-regression-lines-with-ggplot2/) to draw them more conveniently:

```
model.rq <- rq(yvar ~ age, mydata, tau=c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9))
quantile.regressions <- data.frame(t(coef(model.rq)))
colnames(quantile.regressions) <- c("intercept", "slope")
quantile.regressions$quantile <- rownames(quantile.regressions)
g0 + geom_abline(aes(intercept=intercept, slope=slope,
   colour=quantile), show_guide=TRUE, data=quantile.regressions)
```

Alternatively it *is* possible to do this within VGAM, but I'm not sure whether it's what you want/whether the results make sense or not.  The Yeo-Johnson transformation, via `lms.yjn`, allows you to do this even when some data values are negative, but you might look at `?lms.bcg`, `?lms.bcn` for alternatives that work for non-negative data.

```
library("VGAM")
fit <- vgam(yvar ~ s(age, df = 4), lms.yjn, data=mydata,
            control=vgam.control(maxit=100),
            trace=FALSE)
```

We get a warning message:

```
## Warning message:
## In vgam.fit(x = x, y = y, w = w, mf = mf, Xm2 = Xm2, Ym2 = Ym2,  :
##  convergence not obtained in 100 iterations
```

This *might* be because we're overfitting the data using a 4-knot spline model?

Quantile plot (following `example("lms.yjn")`)

```
par(bty = "l", mar = c(5, 4, 4, 3) + 0.1, xpd = TRUE)
qtplot(fit, percentiles = c(10, 50, 90),
        las = 1, ylab = "yvar", lwd = 2, lcol = 4)
```

This is a terrible hack, but if you want access to the raw values so you can plot the curves yourself:

```
pcurves <- qtplot.lmscreg(fit,show.plot=FALSE,
                          percentiles=c(10,50,90))
vals <- data.frame(age=mydata$age,pcurves$fitted.values)
vals <- vals[order(vals$age),]
matplot(vals$age,vals[,-1],type="l",lty=c(2,1,2),col=1,
        xlab="age",ylab="")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need curves rather than straight lines, as seen in growth charts. Can you also show how to use LMS? Because that is used most commonly in construction of growth curves. I am actually using only non-negative variables.

Comment: Thanks again for adding VGAM code. How can I avoid plotting the points on the graph so that only curves are visible?